# How to create Index on already created node using Cypher Query Language without using label in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to create Index on already created node using  Cypher Query Language without using label in Neo4j. i want Manual indexing not auto indexing.

I have typed query

```
 CREATE INDEX ON :name(name);
```

and get

```
   SyntaxException: string matching regex `$' expected but `O' found
==> 
==> Think we should have better error message here? Help us by sending this query to cypher@neo4j.org.
==> 
==> Thank you, the Neo4j Team.
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are not using 2.0.

You can't create an index using Cypher. You would have to create it manually via the api (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create.html) or REST(http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-indexes.html)